# What would be the best way to get cookies from HttpServletRequest object?

Tags: java, servlets, cookies, fortify, ssrf

I have a method which is returning the cookie value, getting the cookie from an auto-wired `HttpServletRequest` object. I'm adding the same cookie to call another service in `restClient`.
Everything is working fine, but when I ran Fortify scan, it has given a high-priority issue that `request.getCookies()` can cause Server-Side Request Forgery. What to do in this case?

I've tried validating the cookie string by doing this

```
StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(StringEscapeUtils.escapeJavaScript(cookie.getValue())));
```

But its of no use.

The code is as follows:

```
Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();

if (cookies == null ) {
    return EMPTY;
}

for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
    if (HeaderConstant.ASESSIONID.equals(cookie.getName())) {
        return StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(
               StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(
               StringEscapeUtils.escapeJavaScript(
               cookie.getValue())));
    }
}
```

So fortify is highlighting this line `"Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();"` as Server side request forgery

Comment: In order to fix the issue, if there is one, you first need to understand what the issue is. Do you understand what a server-side request forgery is? If you do, why do you think that changing the way you read a cookie can change anything?

Comment: A Server-Side Request Forgery occurs when an attacker may influence a network connection made by the application
server. The network connection will originate from the application server's internal IP and an attacker will be able to
use this connection to bypass network controls and scan or attack internal resources that are not otherwise exposed.

Is it a false positive, as per you?

Comment: No, it's not, since you forward the cookie you receive from the browser to your other service. It's up to you to decide if that's a security issue or not. For example, if the cookie is cryptographically signed and the signature is verified, there is no way for a client to counterfeit the cookie. My point is that escaping XML, JS and HTML in the cookie won't change anything. At best, it won't change anything to the cookie, but the client will still be able to pass any value it wants inside it. At worst, it will make the cookie value invalid and the ext. service won't be able to use it.